# Github commandline GHI authentication error

Tags: git, authentication, github, command-line

I'm trying to use ghi against my repo, I have tried multiple ways to setup the ghi config, but none worked. Some of the things I have tried:

1. Set environment variable: GITHUB_USER & GITHUG_TOKEN
2. Run `git config --global github.user <username>` & `git config --global github.token <token>`
3. Simply use the `ghi config --auth <username>` command to set the authentication.

None of the above worked.

When I do

`$ ghi -vv config --auth <username>
===> POST /authorizations {"scopes":["public_repo","repo"],"note":"ghi on <name-mbp.domain>","note_url":"https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi"}
<=== 401: {"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}
                                                     ✔
Bad credentials`

So one thing I notice is that the Documentation_url is that the end point? How would I edit that url to be my end point?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, looks like for the ghi to work with your github through 2FA, all I need was the following two git config:

```
git config github.host <your github host>
git config ghi.token <your personal access token>
```

I'm still getting a `Bad credentials` while trying to `ghi config --auth <username>`, but `ghi list` works. I think with token, then username and password is not needed anymore.